# how to make a REST API call to parse.com to save an object using python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, rest, parse-platform

I am trying to save an object to cloud backend using it's REST API in Python. Below is my code (referenced from [here](http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/python-rest-examples/)) and also the error I am seeing.

Here's my code:

```
import json, httplib

connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection("api.parse.com", 80)
connection.connect()

connection.request('POST', '/1/classes/TestApp', json.dumps({
    "score": 1337,
    "playerName": "Sean Plott",
    "cheatMode": False
}), {
    "X-Parse-application-id": "<my_application_id>",
    "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "<my_rest_api_key>",
    "Content-type": "application/json"
})

result = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read())
```

**Error**:

```
mycomp-MBP:learningpython mycomp$ python parserestapi.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parserestapi.py", line 4, in <module>
    connection.connect()
  File     "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7     /lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1274, in connect
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File     "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7     /lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 352, in wrap_socket
    _context=self)
   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7     /lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 579, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7    /lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 808, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:590)
mycomp:learningpython mycomp$
```

Answer (score 0):

Hate to answer my own question but I just found the answer. The `80` needed to be changed to `443`.
https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#objects-creating-objects